# In R and dplyr, replace multiple calls of "mutate" with a single call using "mutate" and "across"

Tags: r, dplyr

We have the following dataframe in R

```
# Create example dataframe
df <- data.frame(gp = c(0, 1, 0, 1), 
                 col1A = c(1, 2, 3, 4), 
                 col1B = c(5, 6, 7, 8), 
                 col2A = c(11, 12, 13, 14), 
                 col2B = c(15, 16, 17, 18),
                 col3A = c(11, 12, 13, 14), 
                 col3B = c(15, 16, 17, 18))
```

We are looking to apply the following logic:

```
df %>%
  dplyr::mutate(col1A = ifelse(gp == 0, col1B, col1A)) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(col2A = ifelse(gp == 0, col2B, col2A)) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(col3A = ifelse(gp == 0, col3B, col3A))
```

However we are looking to replace the 3 `mutate` calls with 1 call that combines `mutate` and `across` (or some other approach). Assume we have these variables in strings, so `aVars = c('col1A', 'col2A', 'col3A')` and `bVars = c('col1B', 'col2B', 'col3B')`.

Is this type of consolidation possible to do? We've used `mutate` and `across` together before, but it seems more difficult to do so when using two sets of variables like we are doing with the `A` and the `B` variables here...

Comment: Please check your code, you're missing a few close-parens.

Comment: just updated the code

Comment: To have all the commands in one `mutate` statement, just separate each new variable and its associated `ifelse` statement by a comma - ie `df %>% mutate(Col1A = ifelse(...), Col2A = ifelse(...), Col3A = ifelse(...))`

Comment: We are looking to avoid hardcoding `Col1A`, `Col2A`, etc. We have the `aVars` and `bVars` arrays, with matching variable names (except the suffix letter at the end) in each array, but the specific variable names can otherwise be different

Comment: Oh I know - this wasn't an answer just a tip (hence the comment). Good luck!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `cur_column()` and modify it (for the trailing `"B"`) to reference both versions of each variable.

```r
df %>%
  mutate(
    across(ends_with("A"),
           ~ if_else(gp == 0, cur_data()[[sub("A$", "B", cur_column())]], .))
  )
#   gp col1A col1B col2A col2B col3A col3B
# 1  0     5     5    15    15    15    15
# 2  1     2     6    12    16    12    16
# 3  0     7     7    17    17    17    17
# 4  1     4     8    14    18    14    18
```

Comment: this throws an error for me? perhaps I am using a different version of R? Getting ```Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
ℹ `..1 = across(...)`.
x Predicate used in lieu of column selection.
ℹ You most likely meant: `across(everything(), ~...)`.
ℹ The first argument `.cols` selects a set of columns.
ℹ The second argument `.fns` operates on each selected columns.```

Comment: Are your real column names different than here in your sample data?

Comment: this is throwing an error for me even using the sample data - (EDIT has fixed this!)

Comment: Oops, lost a comma after `ends_with("A")`; refresh/reload the page and/or just add the comma.

Comment: accepting this answer (and using this answer in our code) despite the other answer being cleaner syntax because this is a `dplyr` solution which makes it a bit more reliable than a `dplyover` solution.

Answer (score 2):

With `dplyover::across2`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(dplyover)
df %>% 
  mutate(across2(ends_with("A"), ends_with("B"), ~ ifelse(gp == 0, .y, .x), 
                 .names = "{xcol}"))

  gp col1A col1B col2A col2B col3A col3B
1  0     5     5    15    15    15    15
2  1     2     6    12    16    12    16
3  0     7     7    17    17    17    17
4  1     4     8    14    18    14    18
```

---

Maybe a more reliable answer, using `glue` and `rlang`. Specify the columns in `cols`, the function in `exprs` and the names of the new columns in `names(exprs)`:

```r
library(glue)
library(dplyr)

cols <- paste0("col", 1:3)
exprs <- glue("ifelse(gp == 0, {cols}B, {cols}A)")
names(exprs) <- glue("{cols}A")
df %>% 
  mutate(!!!rlang::parse_exprs(exprs))

  gp col1A col1B col2A col2B col3A col3B
1  0     5     5    15    15    15    15
2  1     2     6    12    16    12    16
3  0     7     7    17    17    17    17
4  1     4     8    14    18    14    18
```

Comment: Like this quite a bit, cleaner syntax, looks like the library was built specifically for this type of a use-case. Is `dplyover` a reliable library?

Comment: `dplyover` is not on CRAN, so it's not reliable on that end, but I know that the maintainer is still active: https://github.com/TimTeaFan/dplyover